# Bypass Angular unsafe URL's

Tags: angular

I have a CMS written in Angular 5 where members can add text including links.  The problem is that when the content is rendered with:

```
<div [innerHTML]="model.content"></div>
```

Then the links are rendered as

```
unsafe:\"http://www.example.com\"
```

and I get this warning:

```
WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value \"https://www.example.com/\" (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)
```

How do I disable this?  I have seen similar questions that require each URL to be specifically made safe, but I don't know what url's are going to be input.

As it's a very small user base and partitioned via membership then I don't want to have this extra level of security.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a pipe to reuse it anywhere in your html:

```
@Pipe({name: 'trust'})
export class TrustPipe implements PipeTransform {
   constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
   transform(value) {
     return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
   }
}
```

And then use it in your html:

```
<div [innerHTML]="model.content | trust"></div>
```

Comment: I've imported import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
and { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser"; but bypassSecurityTrustHTML is not resolving

Comment: But you have marked the question as solved. Did you find the issue?

Comment: Yes, I ended up using this https://gist.github.com/Bloggerschmidt/d1c635a9d8ca6d2d8804a16822b72e4e

Answer (score 1):

You should inject `DomSanitizer` to your component and byPassSecurity control.

```
@Component({
   selector: 'my-comp',
   template: `
       <div [innerHTML]="url"></div>
   `
})
export class MyComponent {

   url;
   content;
   constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

   ngOnInit() {
       this.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.content);
   }

}
```

For more info, [check the docs](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer)